# correct item choosed in twig for an edited form (symfony)

Tags: symfony, twig

i want to edit an entity via a form :

```
public function editerOffreAction($slug, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $offre = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Offre')->findOneBySlug($slug);


    $form = $this->createForm(OffreType::class, $offre);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($offre);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_lister_echanges_utilisateur');
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle/Utilisateur/editer.offre.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

}
```

The form looks like :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Sources\TypeIntervenant',
                    'choice_label' => 'nom',
                    'placeholder' => 'choose a type of worker',
                    ));
// I m showing only the field that is important
}
```

the Entity AppBundle:Sources\TypeIntervenant contains two values : profesionnal and not profesional.

Now the problem : when i render the twig view, the field type is on placeholder, even though a type is choosen in the Entity :

```
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.type) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.type) }}
     {{ form_errors(form.type) }}
  </div>
```

How can i make the field type containing the value of the entity when I edit it ?

I tried :

```
   <div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.type) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.type, { 'value' : '1' } ) }}
     {{ form_errors(form.type) }}
  </div>
```

But I want value to be the actual value in the entity !
Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Edit 1 : here is the code of the two entities (i am puting only relevant information as the offre entity is long)

Entity "offre" :

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Offre
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="offre")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\OffreRepository")
 */
class Offre
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $type;

    // AND ALL OTHER FIELDS
    //ETC ...


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set titre
     *
     * @param string $titre
     *
     * @return Offre
     */
    public function setTitre($titre)
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitre()
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return Offre
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

// AND OTHER SETTERS AND GETTERS FOR THE OTHER FIELDS ...

}
```

Entity "TypeIntervenant"

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity\Sources;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TypeIntervenant
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="c_type_intervenant")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TypeIntervenantRepository")
 */
class TypeIntervenant
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $nom;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     *
     * @return TypeIntervenant
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 : here is a dump of the form when I edit it :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlspH.png)

EDIT 3 :

I want to go with the choice solution, so I tried :

```
->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => $this->getTypeTarifications(),
    ))
```

Creating a private function in the Form :

```
private function getTypeTarifications()
{
    $choices = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Sources\TypeTarification')->findAll();
    return ($choices);

}
```

But it does not work !

Comment: Are you sure the relationship to the TypeIntervenant is saved? Show what is dumped entity Offre look like.

Comment: Please post the two entities full classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field type should be a relation:

```
/**
 * @var TypeIntervenant
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Sources\TypeIntervenant")
 */
protected $type;
```

then:

```
$builder->add('type');
```

Note: Form type and class option it not necessary, are resolved automatically based on relation

Comment: Yes thanks. But i want to have a select item with information from a table. Should I build a second table/entity to feed the list?

Comment: I mean : how can i have a list of items in the type field, knowing that i want that list from a table database. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, use the above approach, TypeIntervenant is other entity, with another table with a list of records. In this case is necessary add each type manually in the database to use later, this is commonly when type is dynamic and should be controlled by your application logic.

Comment: hello again, and sorry to bother you.
I just put an image of the FormView when I edit the entity.
You can see that the data field of the type is good ("Particulier").
I would like to be able to edit it without creating the relation etc...

when i put : {{ form_widget(form.type, { 'value' : '1' } ) }} , I get the first field of the select. So do you know how can I put the value that it is in the entity ?

Do you think it is possible ?

Comment: I don't understood your question, if it's another question or problem, please create another issue explaining all details.

Comment: It is the same problem ! I just want to put in the select box the value of the type in the entity, having a string field, and whitout creating relation between offre and type !

Comment: If you need only save the string in the type (without relation) you need to build your select choices manually, loading all options from database, and use a ChoiceType instead of EntityType (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html), or for static types using string use ENUM with (https://github.com/fre5h/DoctrineEnumBundle)

Comment: Ok then i want to go with choicetype solution, but it does not work ! (see my edit).
And thanks again !!

Comment: Choices can`t be instance of objects, modify your query or update the method getTypeTarifications to get array of string. *["Type1"=>"Type1", "Type2" => "Type2"]*

Comment: ADSIVE: if you save the type using the string, when the original type change the name, the type selected differ from origin and does not match any more, in this case you must update selected type string manually. For that reason is recommended use relations.

Comment: Ok thanks for the solution and the advice ! I apreciate